# How to split Iterable in chunks with lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, apache-commons, iterable, sublist

I have 
`Iterable<CSVRecord> = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in)` (apache commons)
records which is > 10.000.000.000 rows. Previously I had for loop with counter and after each x rows I was processing data. Now I try to achieve similar effect with Java 8 lambda expressions.

So far I come up with this, but it runs out of memory as I am unable to find right way how to split that in `subList`

```
  Iterable<List<?>> params = new ArrayList<>(StreamSupport
                .stream(records.spliterator(), true)
                .map(r -> Arrays.asList(
                        r.get("name"),
                        r.get("surname"),
                        r.get("something"),
                ))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).subList(0, 20000));
```

subList at the end doesn't work :(

I just need some proof of concept how to split `Iterable` - e.g. right place where to put `subList`?

Comment: Is `records` a list? If so maybe you could use Lists.partition from guava (there is a version in Iterables too).

Comment: updated my question. debugger says records is `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it with a single lambda expressen, but you can use `.skip()` and `.limit()`:

```
int maxSize = 20000;
int currentOffset = 0; // Increment by maxSize each iteration    
Iterable<List<?>> params = new ArrayList<>(StreamSupport
                            .stream(records.spliterator(), true)
                            .skip(currentOffset)
                            .limit(maxSize)
                            .map(r -> Arrays.asList(
                                    r.get("name"),
                                    r.get("surname"),
                                    r.get("something"),
                            ))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: That worked. I will leave question open for a day if better solution comes up, but so far your answer fits me best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for your case is to separate the data transformation stage and chunking.
For data transformation (records -> arrays) you can use streams or parallel stream. They are shining here. But chunking is not good scenario for the streams as stream can produce one chunk at a time (via skip/limit). So you have to recreate stream for each chunk.
It would be better to use simple loop or some library api (as RC recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Hi i'm not sure if it's looks great but that is another way of handling things.

```
//that can be CsvParser not List
List<Integer> collection = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5);

int limit = 2;
int size =  collection.size();

long maxPartIndex =  (long) Math.ceil((double) size/ limit);

LongStream.range(0, maxPartIndex)
    .mapToObj(partIndex -> getPart(collection.spliterator(), partIndex, limit))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

....

```
private static <T> List<T> getPart(Spliterator<T> stream, long index, long size) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(stream, false)
    .skip(index * size)
    .limit(size)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

output:

(1, 2)
(4, 5)
(2, 1)
(2, 4)
(5)

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer the question of chunking, but... Consider buying more memory. If this is the typical size of the problem set. RAM may work out cheaper than the cost of the extra thinking time to continually write memory-efficient programs.

Comment: Probably, but I like writing memory-efficient programs :)

Comment: You'll never get a job at Microsoft with that kind of attitude.